# Where would I find instructions to drive "Ubuntu Web Browser"?

Tags: browser

I'd like to give it a run, but I cannot use it, and the interface isn't intuitive.

For example, how do I show:

- the address bar
- forward and backward buttons
- activity (history)
- etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your mouse to the button of the screen, and click once, you will get all that.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had clicked everywhere on the screen, but the closest that I got to the bottom must have been 8mm or so. Not close enough. At least I'm in a position to use it now.

Comment: Oh dear. I just discovered that Ctrl-V doesn't work, and there is no contextual menu.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1321920